# Robolectric cannot find AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, robolectric

This test originally ran fine.  Checked out a new branch several days later (with commits from many other developers) and it no longer works.

Test class in the mylibrary library module:

```
import com.company.mylibrary.BuildConfig;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", sdk = 21)
public class MyTest {
```

I have also tried:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest = Config.NONE, sdk = 21)
```

In the library module's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    .
    .
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
```

Error message when running inside AS is:
    `java.lang.RuntimeException: build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml`

Error message when running from command line is:
`com.company.mylibrary.framework1.feature1.MyTest > testMethod STANDARD_ERROR
    java.lang.RuntimeException: build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml`

`A)  Don't know why it is looking there for the manifest
B)  That file/directory does not exist
C)  src/main/AndroidManifest.xml does exist`

Things I have tried:
`- deleted the build directory in that library module
- restarted Android Studio
- Build/Clean
- Build/Rebuild Project
- run the test (both inside AS and from command line)
- and tried different versions of the @Config notation`

Seems to be in a wonky state that I cannot clear.

I am working on a MacBook Pro.  Android Studio 2.0 beta5

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the working directory within the test's run configuration to the module directory.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tackled the issue you're facing right now several times and found solution suitable for myself.

Generally, if your test logic does not require access to the application's resources, it's worth using usual `RobolectricTestRunner` as the time of the test execution is relatively shorter comparing it to the test execution time under `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`.

If, for some reason, you need access to the specific `AndroidManifest.xml` file, IMO it's better to come up with test file rather than to operate on the project's one.

By saying 'test file' I mean the following:
Let's start by defining what are the methods that can help us to obtain path to the resources files. The goal is to be able execute tests under Android Studio and, what's more relevant, via CLI (`gradle :project:testBuildTypeUnitTest`)

1. Java's System class: [System.getProperty('user.dir')](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) returns User's current working directory. Obtaining current directory we are in may help us to obtain paths to the resources we need to run our test having them provided.
2. Overriding `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`. To create our customized test runner we need the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the `res` directory and the `assets` directory paths:

   ```
   public class CompassApplicationRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {

   private static final int TARGET_SDK_VERSION = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
   private static final int MIN_SDK_VERSION = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1;

   public CompassApplicationRobolectricTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
       super(klass);
   }

   @Override
   protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {

       final String manifestPath = PathResolver.resolveAndroidManifestPath();
       final String resourcesPath = PathResolver.resolveResPath();
       final String assetsPath = PathResolver.resolveAssetsPath();

       AndroidManifest manifest = new AndroidManifest(
               Fs.fileFromPath(manifestPath),
               Fs.fileFromPath(resourcesPath),
               Fs.fileFromPath(assetsPath)) {
           @Override
           public int getTargetSdkVersion() {
               return TARGET_SDK_VERSION;
           }

           @Override
           public int getMinSdkVersion() {
               return MIN_SDK_VERSION;
           }
       };

       return manifest;
   }
   }
   ```

Below, is the link to the example that worked for me. It was developed, however, some time ago and from the time perspective I see it can be done more elegant way so if you decide to apply this solution to your project, organize your path constants to be static and immutable:

https://github.com/dawidgdanski/android-compass-api/blob/master/app-tests/src/test/java/pl/dawidgdanski/compass/PathResolver.java

It's worth remembering that `File.separator` returns system's default directories separator. It's extremely useful when it comes to provide system-independent paths separated with default separation symbol.

Eventually, if the solution described above is not the one you want to follow, read decent article about setting up testing environment available here:

http://artemzin.com/blog/how-to-mock-dependencies-in-unit-integration-and-functional-tests-dagger-robolectric-instrumentation/

Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running a single test manually (Right click and run)  from inside Android Studio and Roboelectric wanted a RELEASE version. The question above was about debug but my test runs for some reason wanted a release version of the manifiest.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: build/intermediates/manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml`

I had never done a production build in this project so that build directory had never been created.

After wrestling for a bit with no success (setting the path in configuration, trying to get the path in my CustomRoboelectric file), I just generated a production build so that I had the release path created with a manifest and everything worked.

So my solution was to just run the build to create what Roboelectric wanted.